# Swift - Animate like "Push" when adding manually a view

Tags: swift, swift2

I have a `ViewController` with a "mainView" where I'm loading some `ViewControllers` when a segment element is selected.

```
   let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    self.vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DashboardDetail")

    self.vc.view.frame = self.mainView.bounds
    self.mainView.addSubview(self.vc.view)

    self.addChildViewController(self.vc)
    vc.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

This works fine but I would like to add an animation so It appears like a "Push" in a `NavigationController`.

And I should also add the same animation for dissapearing the view when I remove it. This is the code that I user for remove.

```
self.vc.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)
        self.vc.view.removeFromSuperview()
        self.vc.removeFromParentViewController()
```

> Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into `UIView.transitionWithView` for transitions.

```
func animate() {
let opts : UIViewAnimationOptions = .TransitionFlipFromLeft
UIView.transitionWithView(self.imView, duration: 1, options: opts,
                          animations: {
                            self.imView.image = UIImage(named:"play-button.png")
    }, completion: nil)
```

}

You can also try something like this.

```
extension UIView {

func slidePush(duration: NSTimeInterval = 1.0, completionDelegate: AnyObject? = nil) {
    // Create a CATransition
    let slidePushTransition = CATransition()

    // Set its callback delegate to the completionDelegate
    if let delegate: AnyObject = completionDelegate {
        slidePushTransition.delegate = delegate
    }

    // animation's properties
    slidePushTransition.type = kCATransitionPush
    slidePushTransition.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop
    slidePushTransition.duration = duration
    slidePushTransition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
    slidePushTransition.fillMode = kCAFillModeRemoved

    // Add it to the View's layer
    self.layer.addAnimation(slidePushTransition, forKey: "slidePushTransition")} }
```

and to use the extension `self.view.slidePush()`